# How to convert a Record to a Page that contains that Record with purescript

Tags: arrays, token, record, purescript

I have this function that returns

```
listScheduledPhotos :: ListScheduledPhotosOptions -> ExceptT Error Aff S3ObjectCollection
listScheduledPhotos = resolvePromiseOrThrow <<< _listScheduledPhotos <<< asJS
```

with this type of S3ObjectCollection

```
type S3ObjectCollection
 = { objects :: Array S3Object
   --| An optional token for fetching the next page of objects in the collection
   , continuationToken :: Maybe String
   }
```

and I want it to return this :

```
listScheduledPhotos :: ListScheduledPhotosOptions -> ExceptT Error Aff (Page S3ObjectCollection)
```

so i added a convert function to surround it with a Page :

```
listScheduledPhotos = convertToPage <<< resolvePromiseOrThrow <<< _listScheduledPhotos <<< asJS
```

and type Page have this format

```
data Page a = Page (Maybe PageOptions) (Array a)
```

the `Array a` should have the objects from `objects :: Array S3Object`

and the page options which is defined like this :

```
data PageOptions
  = OnePage
  --| Return all results as one page
  | Token String
  --| Fetch the page associated with the continuation token
  | PageOptions { orderBy :: OrderBy
    , pageSize :: Int
    , offset :: Maybe Int
    }
```

should have the `continuationToken :: Maybe String`

This is the function used to do this :

```
convertToPage :: S3ObjectCollection -> Page S3ObjectCollection
convertToPage a =  Page (a.continuationToken) a.objects
```

and I have this error

```
  Could not match type
          
    String
          
  with type
               
    PageOptions
               

while trying to match type Maybe String
  with type Maybe PageOptions
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: I edited the question please check @FyodorSoikin

Comment: @Ahmed could you add the full error message please? I need to see which function is being called